# Check to see if future objects are equal

Tags: java, string, object, equality

So my question is this:  Can I equate any two objects even if one of those is an object that may be constructed later?
Eg:  In the code below I have a movie creation class and that's all well and good.  I have no issues with that( its just here for context)  the real question is in the Movie Store class.
The Movie Store class initializes three movie objects: Batman, Serenity and Clueless
I want to write a method called rentMovie(String title) which when called will check to see if the title string of the parameter matches the title string of one of the movies.  I know one way to do it would be:

```
if(title.equals("Batman")) //The title being any one of the initialized movies
  {
    movie1.rentMovie(); //rentMovie() also exists in class Movie and is the actual method which does the calculations
    }
```

however this would take multiple if statements and every time I wanted to construct a new movie in the MovieStore class I would have to add a new line of code.  So is there any way to just make this "global" (without a public field)  so that I don't have to define a specific movie title String for rentMovie(String title) to be equal to?

Here is the Movie class:

```
public class Movie
{
    private String title;
    private int cost;
    private int inStock;
    private int totalRentals;
    public Movie(String title, int cost)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.cost = cost;
        inStock = 5+(int)(Math.random()*((15-5)+1)); //random value in interval [5-15]
        totalRentals = 0;        
    }
    public void rentMovie(String title)throws Exception
    {
        if(this.title.equals(title) && inStock>0)
        {
            totalRentals++;
            inStock--;            
        }
        else if(!this.title.equals(title))
        {
           throw new Exception("False. movie rented does not match movie given");            
        }
    }
    public int getCost()
    {
        return cost;
    }

    public int getTotalRentals()
    {
        return totalRentals;
    }

    public void printDetails()
    {
        System.out.println("----------------");
        System.out.println("Title:\t\t"+title);
        System.out.println("Cost:\t\t"+cost);
        System.out.println("In Stock:\t"+inStock);
        System.out.println("Rented:\t\t"+totalRentals);
        System.out.println("----------------");        
    }
}
```

Here is the movie store class:  (I've left the if statement essentially incomplete because I am at a loss on what to do here)

```
public class MovieStore
{
    private Movie movie1;
    private Movie movie2;
    private Movie movie3;
    public MovieStore()
    {
        movie1 = new Movie("Batman",3);
        movie2 = new Movie("Clueless",5);
        movie3 = new Movie("Serenity",4);

    }
    public void rentMovie(String title)
    {
        if(title.equals())    
        {    
          //not sure what to put here.rentMovie(title);
          // there is a bit of a redundacy check here because of Movie class rentMovie() method
          //but I NEED to check the movie titles for equality here first that way I'm sure that rentMovie()
          //from Movie class will run.
            System.out.println("YES"); //used this just to check if what I was doing was working
        }
    }
    public void printDetails()
    {
        movie1.printDetails();
        movie2.printDetails();
        movie3.printDetails();
        int total = (movie1.getCost()*movie1.getTotalRentals())+(movie2.getCost()*movie2.getTotalRentals())+(movie3.getCost()*movie3.getTotalRentals());
        System.out.println(" Total Revenues for Rentals were: " + "$"+total);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the snippet runners?

Comment: Ahh new to the forums I guess it just added them automatically.

Comment: Read up on what the `HashMap` class does.  Make sure you understand it thoroughly.  Then do it the way @MJSG describes.  This is exactly what `HashMap` (and similar classes) are for.

Comment: Will do I'm relatively new to Java used to code in python so I have quite a bit more to learn.

Comment: OK, well a Java `HashMap` is similar in some ways to a Python dictionary.  If that helps.

Comment: Hmm yeah that probably will help thanks but I'll still research it for sure.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Thanks for the edit I wasn't sure whether to use HTML or JavaScript or to just enter a formatted text block so I just went with the one with Java in the name.  I'll remember next time now that I know the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the movie object is looked up using the movie name, so a lookup based solution should work,

Example:
Create a HashMap with key as lower_case(movie-name) and value as Movie object, this will be used to lookup/find whether a movie is available.

Let movieMap be the HashMap

something like the following:

```
Movie movie = movieMap.get(title.toLowerCase());
if (movie == null) {
  // print error message
} else {
  System.out.println("YES");
}
```

Comment: Although the above answer did work I'll keep this in my back pocket thanks!

Comment: @user3483662 Be careful with the words "above" and "below".  Answers don't necessarily remain in the same positions relative to one another, or display in the same order for all users.

Comment: Haha yeah just noticed that its close to midnight over where I am so I'm a bit tired.  I'll keep that in mind for future posts though.

Answer (score 0):

The `Movie` type already has its' title. Instead, your `Movie` method `rentMovie()` should probably look more like,

```
public boolean rentMovie() {
  if (inStock > 0) {
    totalRentals++;
    inStock--;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Then `MovieStore` could use a `List` of movies,

```
public class MovieStore {
    private List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
    public MovieStore() {
        movies.add(new Movie("Batman", 3));
        movies.add(new Movie("Clueless", 5));
        movies.add(new Movie("Serenity", 4));
    }

    public boolean rentMovie(String title) {
        for (Movie m : movies) {
            if (m.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(title)) {
                return m.rentMovie();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void printDetails() {
        int total = 0;
        for (Movie m : movies) {
            m.printDetails();
            total += m.getCost() * m.getTotalRentals();
        }
        System.out.println(" Total Revenues for Rentals were: " + "$"+total);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response i'll try it right away.

Comment: does the List class need to be imported?  I'm making these two classes from scratch and I did not anticipate the need for importing.  The error I'm getting is:  Cannot find symbol - class List

Comment: Yes. Import `java.util.List` and `java.util.ArrayList`.

Comment: to get it to print out the details would I then simply print out the list of movies?

Comment: @user3483662 Edited to add `printDetails()`. To simply print the `List` of movies, your class `Movie` would need to override `toString()` - but that wouldn't give you a total.

Comment: Great thanks a ton!  that really worked and made the difference.  Way more fluid than having an overflow of if statements.